# PHP function to match key in a range of values

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have a array with the `lvl=>xp` correspondance and I would make a function that return the lvl for a specific xp. like `$lvl = getLvlOf(15084); //return 5`

```
$lvl_correspondance = array(
    1=>100,
    2=>520,
    3=>2650,
    4=>6588,
    5=>12061,
    6=>23542,
    ...
    n=>xxxxxx
);
```

I search the easyest and ressourceless way to do it.

Sorry for my poor english :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the level values in the array are kept sorted, e.g. (it's 100,200,300, 400, etc... and not 200,500,100,300,400), then a simple scan will do the trick:

```
$xp = 15084;
$last_key = null;
foreach($lvl_correspondenance as $key => $val) {
    if ($val < $xp) {
        $last_key = $key;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

That'll iterate through the array, and jump out as soon as the XP level in the array is larger than the XP level you're looking for, leaving the key of that "last" level in $last_key

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if ($val <= $xp) `?

Comment: Depends on if you get bumped to a higher level on reaching 100 (say) or at 101, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getLvlOf($lvl, $int){
        foreach($lvl as $level=>$exp){
                if($exp > $int){
                        return $level-1;
                }
        }
}
```

it's O(n) so no magic there...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your array can be computed live -

> XP = exp( 3 * ln(LVL) + 4 ) * 2

You can do the same in reverse, in O(1):

> LVL = exp(ln(XP/2) - 4 / 3)

I rounded the equation, so there may be a +/- 1 issue

Good Luck!

Comment: It a perfect hasard if it can be computed live. I already try to do this but there is 100 lvl and I didn't find formul for that. But thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: May be you can find a formul with the real data here https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0AtG26dlTOqfzdDc0Z1p5NGdJdVB2cXl0ckFqbVhHVEE&hl=fr&authkey=CPCY2PsP ?

Comment: Best fit is a 4-order polynomial: `XP = 0.014*L^4 - 1.83*L^3 + 108.67*L^2 - 1563.36*L + 6830` this is ridiculous, and it would be better if you knew where the numbers came from originally

Answer (score 0):

Not good if you have very high level values, but:

```
$lvl = $lvl_correspondance[array_search(
                                 max(array_intersect(
                                           array_values($lvl_correspondance),
                                                        range(0,$points)
                                                       )
                                    ),
                                 $lvl_correspondance
                                )];
```

Comment: Its a great idea but its realy realy bad performance for my type of value. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Never said it was efficient, just an alternative way of doing it :-)

Answer (score -2):

You can use [array_flip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) if the xp levels are distinct. Then you can simply access the level number using the xp as index:

```
$levels = array_flip($lvl_correspondance);
$lvl = $levels[15084];
```

---

**EDIT:** But maybe a function would be better to fetch even the xp levels in between:

```
function getLvlOf($xp) {
  // get the levels in descending order
  $levels = array_reverse($GLOBALS['lvl_correspondance'], true);

  foreach ($levels as $key => $value) {
    if ($xp >= $value)
      return $key;
  }

  // no level reached yet
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: And if the level doesn't exist, you get null. OP wants "nearest" value.

Comment: It's not a look up, it's a value between two levels

Comment: Just make sure that values are all unique. From the php manual `If a value has several occurrences, the latest key will be used as its values, and all others will be lost.`

Comment: @Marc B: the OP said "return the lvl for a _specific_ xp". I gave a solution to that. Right after that I've editted in a solution that I find better.